# Call controller action from bootstrap modal in grails

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, grails

I am using grails 2.4.2 and bootstrap. Now I need to use bootstrap modal to edit a individual row on click a button. It means that when I will click the action button the modal will open with form element. After giving value in the modal field I want to press the save change button to call controller action but its not happening.Can anyone please help me on this please? Here are my attempts below ::

the button form where I am opening the modal in edit form ::

```
<span>
 <a href="" title="Change File" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
 </a>
</span>
```

my modal & elements ::

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Add Video</h4>
            </div>

            <g:form controller="video" action="updateAddVideo" method="PUT" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h5>Edit</h5>
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel panel-body">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <g:hiddenField name="addVideoId" value=""/>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <label>Add Title</label>
                                    <g:textField name="addTitle" required="" class="form-control"/>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <label>Upload Add Video</label>
                                    <input type="file" id="videoName" name="videoName" required="" class="form-control"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </g:form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might need to change your `<button>` tags to be of type `<input type="submit"...>`.
The button element does not automatically cause a submit action when pressed, unless you add code to the "onClick" property to do so. Using a input type submit button should tell the form to submit to its controller.

Alternatively, look into grails "actionSubmit" tag, which works with g:form.
[Grails Documentation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/actionSubmit.html)